# Need dataset for second hand product sales of an e-commerce site like olx

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I wish to do analysis of second hand products sold online please tell me from where i can get dataset. Dataset can contain fields like user-id, name of product, selling price, date of sell etc

Comment: is there anyone who can help me

Comment: some individuals have used craigslist posting archives for analysis purposes. You may want to google/look around for some archived sources (like archive.org).